# ASP.NET - How do I reference a classproject in my web application

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to develop a 3-tier architecture. For that I've created a BAL(class project) and DAL(class project). I want to reference BAL to my web application and also DAL to BAL.

Should I reference the BAL.dll(got when compiling the BAL class project) or the BAL classproject as aa whole.

What's the correct approach and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reference the class project as a whole.  In Visual Studio right click on the project that you want to add the reference to (in your case the BAL project), click add reference.  Now depending which version of Visual Studio you are running the next window you see will look slightly different.  In Visual Studio 2012, click the solution option on the left, then you can check the project you want to reference.  Hit ok that's it.  You should see the project appear in the list of references under the project (you may need to expand it).  In Visual Studio 2010 for the last step you click on the projects option on the left, then click on the project you want to add and hit ok.

Comment: Thankyou bro for the reply.I think in this case even if we make some changes in BAL,there is no need to add the reference once again..

Answer (score 0):

To execute your web project, you have to add a reference of the BAL.dll in your web project and DAL.dll in your BAL project. If you want to access the source code of BAL and DAL project then it is recomended to including all the project under single solution. But for executing you need only the .dll file in this case.

Comment: In this case i think if i make some change in the BAL class project, i should reference the dll once again into my web application.

Comment: @Kevin Holditch the procedure is right. But it will refer the dll file only. We need the dll file only to use the external component in our code. You can see the reference dll file at your bin folder.

Comment: @ksg you do not need to refer again after making any modification as long as you have refer the correct dll file.